# AJV: no schema with key or ref "https://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema"

Tags: ajv

I am using ajv 8.6.2

I have schemas that validate against draft-07 using the [default export](https://ajv.js.org/json-schema.html#draft-07)

When I use the [draft-09 export](https://ajv.js.org/json-schema.html#draft-2019-09) all of my schemas give me this error:

```
no schema with key or ref "https://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema"
```

Same error exists if I use this:

```
no schema with key or ref "https://json-schema.org/draft-09/schema"
```

Can't seem to figure out what's going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean by

> When I use the draft-09 export all

that you're using `Ajv2019` instance

```js
import Ajv2019 from "ajv/dist/2019"
const ajv = new Ajv2019()
```

then you need to add the `draft-07` metaschema:

```js
const draft7MetaSchema = require("ajv/dist/refs/json-schema-draft-07.json")
ajv.addMetaSchema(draft7MetaSchema)
```

as explained at https://ajv.js.org/guide/schema-language.html#draft-2019-09-and-draft-2020-12

FYI, don't refer to JSON meta schemas with `https://`, their identifiers do start with `http://`, `ajv` doesn't retrieve them, it packages them instead.

Answer (score 7):

AJV does not seem to support HTTPs versions of the json-schema identifiers; try using `http:` instead:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are receiving `no schema with key or ref` is because JSON Schema `$id` keyword is merely an identifier, it's not expected to resolve to any network location. That's not to say it *isn't* possible to resolve, only that the spec indicates it's not expected and the behavior is only an identifier. The JSON Schema specification expects the implementation to "load" all schemas prior to validation. This is typically some sort of registry in memory at runtime. So, ajv doesn't recognize the identifier provided because it doesn't match any known schema to the implementation, unless you were to add it manually with the `addSchema` method.